# XSLT copy-of - attribute left blank

Tags: xslt

I am trying to modify an existing XSLT to include the originalfilename attribute of the file node in the input XML as the file attribute of feedback in the output xml. I think I'm misunderstanding the copy-of statement and I would be very extremely grateful for any help. At the moment my desired output is displaying an empty file attribute on the feedback node.

## XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <document>
      <xsl:for-each select="files/file/segmentpair[Comments/Comment]">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Comments/Comment" />
        <xsl:copy-of select="files|file|source|target" />
      </xsl:for-each>
    </document>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Comment">
    <feedback>
      <xsl:attribute name="id">
        <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding::Comments)+1" />
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="file">
        <xsl:value-of select="files/file/@originalfilename" />
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </feedback>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

## Input

```
<files>
  <file originalfilename="C:\Users\A\Documents\Studio 2014\Projects\15_002_\de-DE\master\advanced-materials-and-processes-msc-hons.xml">
    <segmentpair id="1" locked="False" color="245,222,179" match-value="86">
      <source>Advanced Materials and Processes (M.Sc.hons.)</source>
      <target>Advanced Materials and Processes (MSc)</target>
      <Comments>
        <Comment>[ic14epub 20.01.2015 09:28:43] 'hons' taken out (discussion of this still ongoing as far as I'm aware)</Comment>
      </Comments>
    </segmentpair>
 </file>
</files>
```

## Desired Output

```
    <feedback id="1" file="C:\Users\A\Documents\Studio 2014\Projects\15_002_\de-DE\master\advanced-materials-and-processes-msc-hons.xml">[ic14epub 20.01.2015 09:28:43] 'hons' taken out (discussion of this still ongoing as far as I'm aware)</feedback>
       <source>Advanced Materials and Processes (M.Sc.hons.)</source>
       <target>Advanced Materials and Processes (MSc)</target>
```

Comment: Are you iterating over files/file/segmentPair because there might be more than one? If there is more than one, do you want the same source and target output each time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the `@originalfilename` of the first `<file>` ancestor for that `<Comment>`.

```
<xsl:template match="Comment">
  <feedback 
    id="{count(preceding::Comments)+1}"
    file="{ancestor::file[1]/@originalfilename}"
  >
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
  </feedback>
</xsl:template>
```

Note the attribute value templates (curly braces). They can save quite a lot of typing.

Answer (score 1):

You can get your desired output simply by adding a `/`  before `files` in your `<xsl:value-of>`

```
<xsl:value-of select="/files/file/@originalfilename"/>
```

However, I would recommend to use

```
<xsl:value-of select="../../../@originalfilename"/>
```

instead of the absolute path, so it will still works if you have more files.

Comment: Thanks not using an absolute path solves the problem, however I accepted Tomalak's answer because the reference to attribute value templates was a useful learning point.